# Debugging a SQL syntax error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, syntax

I'm trying to use PDO on my register and log in page , and started working on my register page and have an syntax error not sure why.

The error is below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO users (id, name, username, password, lastname ,email) VALUES (?, ?,' at line 1

Code:

```
 if ($_SESSION["username"]){

 header("Location: home.php");
 }
else{
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) &&    isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['cpassword'])  && isset($_POST['email'])){
     require('connect.php');

     $dusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
    $dfirstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]);
     $dpassword = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]));
    $dlastname =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastname"]);
    $demail =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);




$dbhost = "xxxxxxx"; 
$dbname= "xxxxxx";
$dbuser = "xxxx";
$mysql_password = "xxxxx";



 try{


 $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf8',   

 ''.$dbuser.'',    

 ''.$mysql_password.'');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}

catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
die();


}

 mysql_error();
  //According to user's input
 $register =mysql_query( "(INSERT INTO users (id, name, username, password, lastname,email)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")or die(mysql_error());
 $register =$db->prepare($register);
 $register->execute(array($dfirstname,$dusername,$dpassword,$dlastname,$demail));

// Check username and password match
if ($register) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
// Jump to secured page
header('Location: home.php');
exit;
}
else{

  echo "<div class=\"error\">Error Signing Up... Make Sure all the require 

  fields         are correctly formatted. </div>";
    }
    }
 else{

 }
 }
```

Updated it

```
  $register ="INSERT INTO users (id, name, username, password, lastname ,email) VALUES('',?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"or die(mysql_error());
  $register =$db->prepare($register);
  $register->execute(array('',$dfirstname,$dusername,$dpassword,$dlastname,$demail));
```

Still have the error

Comment: the `INSERT INTO`,line is where it is saying the error is

Comment: you cannot mix `mysql_*` functions and `PDO` methods, stick with `PDO`

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: so mysql_query i don't need it? @Ghost

Comment: @FollowerofChrist you wouldn't need one bit of it, all of this can be done with just PDO

Comment: Why you use mysql_real_escape_string in PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$register->execute(array($dfirstname,$dusername,$dpassword,$dlastname,$demail));
```

should be

```
$register->execute(array('',$dfirstname,$dusername,$dpassword,$dlastname,$demail));
```

Comment: thanks for the edit but the error still exist @virendra

Comment: also change this one
 
$register =mysql_query( "(INSERT INTO users (id, name, username, password, lastname,email)  VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 1):

You have 6 columns in your `insert` statement but only 5 values in the `values` clasue. That should also be 6.